# How to reset the Cipher to the state at the time of initialization?

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

To preserve the key, the iv, and the mode of operation and to reset all buffers and so on.
doFinal() call is that correct?
But doFinal () will do the extra work. And I do not need previous data.

```
Cipher с=Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
с.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
....

void Decode(Cipher c)
{
   c.doFinal();//reset cipher !?
   //Start a new decoding session
   ....
}
```

Comment: Create a new `Cipher` object, maybe?

Comment: @ArtjomB.
It is possible of course, but I would be more convenient to use one copy.

Comment: No, it would be a pretty bad idea to just use one copy, especially if you cannot tell the state of the `Cipher` instance. `Cipher` instances are not that resource heavy and you probably need a new initialization vector anyway *right?*

Comment: I will explain why I need it. 
The Decode function is necessary for decoding of small pieces of the same file. 
Encrypted data is interleaved with headers without encryption. 
I.e Cipher in my case is not changed and the same for all pieces.
I assumed that doFinal in 99% of cases will do nothing. 
As the data in the cache Cipher can only result in errors or exceptions at the time of encryption of the previous piece.
I.e this approach should work as quickly as possible. 
It is important that this method from the point of view of the integrity of the data can be used. What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

You call `Cipher.init(),` of course.

You just need to rearrange your API so that the correct parameters are provided to your methods so they can call `init()`.

You will probably need a new initialization vector for each separate encrypt/decrypt anyway.

Comment: Sometimes you do need to encrypt/decrypt a lot of small pieces of data with the same IV (or in ECB mode). Cipher.init() has a lot of overhead because every call checks the SPI, export limitations based on key size, exemptions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! You don't need to do anything. After a call to doFinal() the cipher resets itself to its initial state. Here is a demonstration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Cipher aes = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec("YELLOW SUBMARINE".getBytes(), "AES");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);

    aes.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

    byte[] cipherText = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary("60FA36707E45F499DBA0F25B922301A57192FEBE51B66D25BBFCC348138FD3F7");

    System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(aes.doFinal(cipherText)));
    System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(aes.doFinal(cipherText)));
}
```

I get the output:

```
10101010101010101010101010101010
10101010101010101010101010101010
```

Please note that the [Java Sun Crypto provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html) calls it PKCS5PADDING instead of PKCS7. If you are using a different crypto provider, use as advised in its documentation. Note that I made the cipher text by encrypting 16 0x10 bytes. I assumed it wouldn't pad it, but it did.

Comment: Not incorrect, but `doFinal` was already mentioned in the question.

Comment: It seems that  doFinal() does not really reset anything.The init() does on the other hand.

Comment: If your cipher-text fills the the last encrypted block fully you get another full block of padding ;)

Comment: Even though this might work now, it's not a good idea to use it because it's not documented. The behaviour might change with a different version, and you'll end up with corrupted data.